# Perl: Substitute text string with value from list (text file or scalar context)

Tags: perl, list, foreach, substitution

I am a perl novice, but have read the "Learning Perl" by Schwartz, foy and Phoenix and have a weak understanding of the language. I am still struggling, even after using the book and the web.

My goal is to be able to do the following:

1. Search a specific folder (current folder) and grab filenames with full path. Save filenames with complete path and current foldername.
2. Open a template file and insert the filenames with full path at a specific location (e.g. using substitution) as well as current foldername (in another location in the same text file, I have not gotten this far yet).
3. Save the new modified file to a new file in a specific location (current folder).

I have many files/folders that I want to process and plan to copy the perl program to each of these folders so the perl program can make new .

I have gotten so far ...:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;
my $current_dir = getcwd;
open SECONTROL_TEMPLATE, '<secontrol_template.txt' or die "Can't open SECONTROL_TEMPLATE: $!\n";
my @secontrol_template = <SECONTROL_TEMPLATE>;
close SECONTROL_TEMPLATE;
opendir(DIR, $current_dir) or die $!;
my @seq_files = grep {
    /gz/
    } readdir (DIR);
open FASTQFILENAMES, '> fastqfilenames.txt' or die "Can't open fastqfilenames.txt: $!\n";
my @fastqfiles;
foreach (@seq_files) {
    $_ = File::Spec->catfile($current_dir, $_);
    push(@fastqfiles,$_);
}
print FASTQFILENAMES @fastqfiles;
open (my ($fastqfilenames),  "<", "fastqfilenames.txt") or die "Can't open fastqfilenames.txt: $!\n";
my @secontrol;
foreach (@secontrol_template) {
    $_ =~ s/@/$fastqfilenames/eg;
    push(@secontrol,$_);
}
open SECONTROL, '> secontrol.txt' or die "Can't open SECONTROL: $!\n";
print SECONTROL @secontrol;
close SECONTROL;
close FASTQFILENAMES;
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to use my list of files to replace the "@" in my template text file:

```
my @secontrol;
foreach (@secontrol_template) {
    $_ =~ s/@/$fastqfilenames/eg;
    push(@secontrol,$_);
}
```

The substitute function will not replace the "@" with the list of files listed in $fastqfilenames. I get the "@" replaced with GLOB(0x8ab1dc).

Am I doing this the wrong way? Should I not use substitute as this can not be done, and then rather insert the list of files ($fastqfilenames) in the template.txt file? Instead of the $fastqfilenames, can I substitute with content of file (e.g. s/A/{r file.txt ...). Any suggestions?

Cheers,

JamesT

**EDIT:**

This made it all better.

```
foreach (@secontrol_template) {
    s/@/$fastqfilenames/g;
    push @secontrol, $_;
}
```

And as both suggestions, the $fastqfiles is a filehandle.

replaced this:    <strike>open (my ($fastqfilenames),  "<", "fastqfilenames.txt") or die "Can't open fastqfilenames.txt: $!\n";</strike>

with this:

```
my $fastqfilenames = join "\n", @fastqfiles;
```

made it all good. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$fastqfilenames` is a filehandle.  You have to read the information out of the filehandle before you can use it.

However, you have other problems.

You are printing all of the filenames to a file, then reading them back out of the file.  This is not only a questionable design (why read from the file again, since you already have what you need in an array?), it also won't even work:

Perl buffers file I/O for performance reasons.  The lines you have written to the file may not actually be there yet, because Perl is waiting until it has a large chunk of data saved up, to write it all at once.

You can override this buffering behavior in a few different ways (closing the file handle being the simplest if you are done writing to it), but as I said, there is no reason to reopen the file again and read from it anyway.

Also note, the `/e` option in a regex replacement evaluates the replacement as Perl code.  This is not necessary in your case, so you should remove it.

**Solution:** Instead of reopening the file and reading it, just use the `@fastqfiles` variable you previously created when replacing in the template.  It is not clear exactly what you mean by replacing `@` with the filenames.

- Do you want to to replace each `@` with a list of all filenames together?  If so, you should probably need to [`join` the filenames](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) together in some way before doing the replacement.
- Do you want to create a separate version of the template file for each filename?  If so, you need an inner `for` loop that goes over each filename for each template.  And you will need something other than a simple replacement, because the replacement will change the original string on the first time through.  If you are on Perl 5.16, you could use the `/r` option to replace non-destructively:  `push(@secontrol,s/@/$file_name/gr);` Otherwise, you should copy to another variable before doing the replacement.

Comment: I am a novice and hence the design of my program is poor. This has to do with I use "what I understand how to use" or what I figure out. The list of filenames in `@fastqfiles` can be used to replace the symbol @ in the template file, but I don't know how to to that (except some basic knowledge in Unix sed/awk, hence the substitution attempt). I don't know how to loop and save the content of `@fastqfiles` into my template file (stored in `@secontrol_template`). I thought I could understand to use a scalar/list of the `@fastqfiles` array in substitution. Maybe, that is part of the design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

`$_ =~ s/@/$fastqfilenames/eg;`

`$fastqfilenames` is a file handle, not the file contents.

In any case, I recommend the use of [Text::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aTemplate) module in order to do this kind of work (file text substitution).

Comment: The [Text::Template] (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aTemplate) link was very useful. I might use it to modify my template file. Absolutely something to look into. Thanks :)